# How to display angular js bar graph in modal popups

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Hi I am trying to display angular js bar chart in modal popup (jquery modal), But its not working. I have tried with the below code.

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                        <div class="modal-content widg_larg">
                            <div class="title">Modal Title
                              <span class="pull-right cursor_pointer">
                                <i class="fa fa-times" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></i>
                              </span>
                              <div ng-controller="testConrtoller">
                              <canvas class="chart chart-bar" data="data"
                            labels="labels" width="400" height="400"></canvas> 
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and js code is

```
app.controller("testController", function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
          $scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];
          $scope.data = [
            [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
            [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
          ];
          $scope.onClick = function (points, evt) {
            console.log(points, evt);
          };
        });
```

But its not working is there any other way to work with it.

Comment: If you adding the html to the DOM yourself (as opposed to using a directive) you'll need to $compile it. I can't tell if that's the problem until I see more code.

Comment: Use directives not jQuery in angular. Try ng-dialog very well written modal pop up. https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog

Comment: Its working fine if I display bar chart simply instead of modal popup

Comment: Yup, but if you use a jquery modal, you'll probably have to compile the content of the modal using ``$compile`` when that modal is displayed. Provide a jsfiddle if you want more help.